# wpf issue with animation

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a xaml view which contains an animation that I put into a content control. In the code behind for the xaml, I load the animation through storyboard find resources. This is fine so far. What I'm having issue is in my xaml there's a button which triggers a relay command from the view model, execute database calls then prompt a message. What I want to achieve is when I click on the button, I would like to show the animation and then when the message box show, i would like to hide the animation. So far no luck.

MainView

```
<ContentControl Name="loader" />

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Content="Test" Command="{Binding TestCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

MainView.cs

```
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _loading = new LoadingUC();  
    _loaderUC = _loading;         
    showLoading.Content = _loaderUC;

    Storyboard showUC = FindResource("Test_Loading") as Storyboard;
    showUC.Begin(_loaderUC);    
}
```

TestViewModel

```
public ICommand TestCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _TestCommand ?? (_TestCommand = new RelayCommand(p => TestSave()));
    }
}

private void TestSave()
{
// show loading
    if (SaveSuccessFul() == true)
    {
        //hide loading
        MessageBox.Show("Save Completed");

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so the error or problem you are facing is what? What's your question?

Comment: Please, post your code so we can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ViewModel can raise an event just before showing the message box.

```
public event EventHandler LoadSuccessful;

private void TestSave()
{
// show loading
    if (SaveSuccessFul() == true)
    {
        //hide loading
        if (LoadSuccessful != null)
           LoadSuccessful(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        MessageBox.Show("Save Completed");

    }
}
```

The view can register to that event and stop the animation when the event is received.

```
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _loading = new LoadingUC();  
    _loaderUC = _loading;         
    showLoading.Content = _loaderUC;

    Storyboard showNewPatUC = FindResource("Test_Loading") as Storyboard;
    showNewPatUC.Begin(_loaderUC);  
}

void OnLoadSuccessful(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Storyboard showNewPatUC = FindResource("Test_Loading") as Storyboard;
    showNewPathUC.Stop();
}
```

Comment: @ Alex Gelman - can you please help?

Comment: I've added a code example. I don't know how you hook the view with the viewmodel so I omitted the code that registers to the `LoadSuccessful` event in the view.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to set up the event to make this work with my view and viewmodel. I'm hooking the view with the viewmodel like so: <Window.Resources> <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:RecoveredDocumentsViewModel}"> <vw:RecoveredDocumentsView /> </DataTemplate> </Window.Resources>

Comment: check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424202/how-can-i-have-a-wpf-eventtrigger-on-a-view-trigger-when-the-underlying-viewmode/1996324#1996324