# System.Windows.Interactivity - exception while loading assembly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-assembly, blend

After I had added some new references to View in my WPF application, I got an exception:

```
{"Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"}
```

StackTrace:

```
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
at MyApplication.GUI.MyPage.InitializeComponent() in c:\Users\Dl\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyApplication\MyApplication.GUI\MyPage.xaml:line 1
at MyApplication.GUI.MyPage..ctor(SettingsViewModel settingsViewModel) in c:\Users\Dl\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyApplication\MyApplication.GUI\MyPage.xaml.cs:line 13
```

And this is the code that causes Exception:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <si:DataEventTrigger EventName="MyEvent">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource MyStoryboard}" 
               ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
    </si:DataEventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The references I added:

```
Microsoft.Expression.Interactions (ver. 4.5)
System.Windows.Interactivity (ver. 4.5)
Expression.Samples.Interactivity (ver. 1.0.0.0)
```

I have no idea where System.Windows.Interactivity 3.5 dependency comes from. Could you give me a clue?

BTW: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424202/how-can-i-have-a-wpf-eventtrigger-on-a-view-trigger-when-the-underlying-viewmode/1996324) may clarify my intentions.

Comment: System.Windows.Interactivity is a dll that comes with Blend. You may want to copy the dll into the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soulution is to reference assemblies provided by blend rather than those from .NET Framework 4.5.

Thank you Magus for your help. You put me on the right truck.

Comment: It's more likely that the Expression.Samples is referencing an old version.